# illegal request error, while connecting vtiger crm with IP:PORT on other computer

Tags: database, vtiger

I am using Vtiger CRM on localhost and for single machine only, 
This time when i tried to connect Vtiger on other computer through http://ipaddress_of_1st_machine:8888 then getting "Illegal Request Error".

When i am clicking on "GO BACK" option which is coming at bottom of Illegal Request Error Box, then it is rendering me on home-page but again after clicking on every module or activity same Illegal Request is getting. Means not able to access 1st machine's database

Kindly help me out or tell me what to do to access that, I tried my best. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From vtiger 6 onwards, there is a security check added to enforce that the value of the $site_URL variable under config.inc.php is same as the url you are trying to access.

Since you have installed it from localhost, i am guessing it is set as http://localhost/[something] and you are trying to access http://[server-ip]/[something] which is why you are getting the error.

To resolve, you just need to change the localhost to the [server-ip] in the $site_URL variable in the config.inc.php

Comment: I solved that problem day before, by changing the same URL !! Anyways thanks for your response. :)